# MPMediaItemCollection Delete selected que/collection?

Tags: iphone, ipod, mpmediaitemcollection

I am currently looking at Apple's [AddMusic example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html) and playing around with it before I start rewriting it into my application.

I noticed that it makes its own little playlist of the songs qued. I want to use the swipe action on the table view to remove songs that a use clicked by mistake.

I have implemented the swipe action but can't work out a way to delete that specific row?

Any idea would be great, below is the code to add it. I tried doing the reverse with no luck. If it's not possible how should I go about it?

Cheers

```
MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController *) self.delegate;
MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = mainViewController.userMediaItemCollection;
MPMediaItem *anItem = (MPMediaItem *)[currentQueue.items objectAtIndex: row];
```

Answer (score 4):

An MPMediaItemCollection is immutable, ie. you can't change the items. You need to create a new one with all items less the one you want to remove. See below:

```
NSArray* items = [currentQueue items];
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[items count]];
[array addObjectsFromArray:items];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:row];
MPMediaItemCollection* newCollection = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:array];
```

Be careful to not create an empty collection. It's not allowed and the MPMediaItemCollection will raise an exception.